# Each loop skipping an element when deleting an element within the each loop

Tags: ruby

I was just messing about trying to get all the 2, 3 and 4 combos in a size 4 array (e.g 1&2,1&3,1&4,2&3 and so on) and I came across this weird issue that I cannot figure out. Why is primary_num returning 4 on the 3rd loop but the index 0 value is 3, shouldn't it return 3.

The code is partial code but obviously can't complete it until I figure this part out. My next plan was to try a recursive function but was curious why this is happening when it works fine on loop 1 & 2. I know there is a permutations method but I am just experimenting.

```
lucky15 = [1,2,3,4]

doubles = []
triples = []
fourfold = []

lucky15.each_with_index do |primary_num, index|
    
    lucky15.delete(index)
    p lucky15[0]
    p primary_num
    p lucky15
end
```

The output for the puts was:

```
1 #p lucky15[0]
1 #p primary_num
[1, 2, 3, 4]

2 #p lucky15[0]
2 #p primary_num
[2, 3, 4]

3 #p lucky15[0]
4 #p primary_num <--- why 4 not 3????
[3, 4]
```

To explain what I was trying to do as my first revision:

```
lucky15 = [1,2,3,4]

doubles = []
triples = []
fourfold = []

lucky15.each_with_index do |primary_num, index|
  lucky15.delete(index)

  each.lucky15 do |num|
    doubles << "#{primary_num} && #{num}"
  end
end

puts doubles
```

Comment: One way you can get those combinations as follows. `(1..2**n-1).each_with_object([]) { |e,a| b = arr.select.with_index { |_,i| e[i] == 1 }; a << b unless b.size == 1 } #=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4], [2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`. See [Integer#\[\]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: As a rule of thumb: don’t modify a collection while traversing it (unless the method(s) specifically say you can)

Comment: You can do a `lucky15.dup.each_with_index` to ensure that the collection you are iterating over is a different object from the one you are modifying. It does not mean that your code will necessarily produce the expected outcome afterwards, because as far as I can see, you never explain the purpose of your program.

Comment: As Stefan already wrote do not delete elements from an array while iterating. Imagine you have `[1,2,3].each` and in the first iteration you delete the `1`. Which results in `[2,3]` what element do you expect to be returned in the second iteration? `2` because it was the second element when the `each` was initialized? Or `3` because it is now the second element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> trying to get all the 2, 3 and 4 combos

To calculate combinations manually, you typically use nested loops. For "doubles", you could use:

```
lucky15 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
doubles = []

(0...lucky15.size-1).each do |i|
  (i+1...lucky15.size).each do |j|
    doubles << lucky15.values_at(i, j)
  end
end

doubles #=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

The outer loop increments an index `i` from `0` to `2` (because `2` is the maximum starting-index for a "2 combo"). The inner loop then increments another index `j` from `i`'s successor up to `3` (the array's end index). This way, the inner loop "skips" the indices that have already been visited by `i`: (so there's no need to delete anything)

```
1 2 3 4  # array values
0 1 2 3  # array indices
i j      # lucky15.values_at(0, 1)

1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
i   j    # lucky15.values_at(0, 2)

1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
i     j  # lucky15.values_at(0, 3)

1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
  i j    # lucky15.values_at(1, 2)

1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
  i   j  # lucky15.values_at(1, 3)

1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
    i j  # lucky15.values_at(2, 3)
```

To get "triples", you need another level:

```
triples = []

(0...lucky15.size-2).each do |i|
  (i+1...lucky15.size-1).each do |j|
    (j+1...lucky15.size).each do |k|
      triples << lucky15.values_at(i, j, k)
    end
  end
end

triples #=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Visualized:

```
1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
i j k

1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
i j   k

1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
i   j k

1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
  i j k
```

However, Ruby already has the above methods built-in as [`combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Array.html#combination-method) so there's no need to re-invent the wheel:

```
doubles = lucky15.combination(2).to_a
#=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]

triples = lucky15.combination(3).to_a
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `delete` method wasn't doing what you thought it was (same here, I had to run a modified version of this with more printing to see it):

```rb
lucky15 = [1,2,3,4]

doubles = []
triples = []
fourfold = []

lucky15.each_with_index do |primary_num, index|
    puts "Index: #{index}"   
    puts "0th element before delete: #{lucky15[0]}"
    lucky15.delete(index)
    puts "0th element after delete: #{lucky15[0]}"
    puts "primary_num: #{primary_num}"
    puts "lucky15: #{lucky15}"
end
```

Output:

```
Index: 0
0th element before delete: 1
0th element after delete: 1
primary_num: 1
lucky15: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Index: 1
0th element before delete: 1
0th element after delete: 2
primary_num: 2
lucky15: [2, 3, 4]
Index: 2
0th element before delete: 2
0th element after delete: 3
primary_num: 4
lucky15: [3, 4]
```

The `index` variable is holding the index each time, but `delete` is searching for the element in the array and deleting it if it's present. So when you use `delete` that way, you're deleting an element equal to the index from the array during each iteration, if such an element exists in the array during that iteration.

You probably want `delete_at` (https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at).